# DbContext multithreading issue with ASP.NET Core middleware

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, middleware, dbcontext, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a middleware registered once. It contains `InvokeAsync`.

I noticed that sometimes I get errors due to multithreaded access to the `DbContext` which I'm not doing. The problem I found that somehow my middleware is called twice per request. And since there is `DbContext`, it causes multithreading issue.

Simplified code:

```
public class UserIdMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UserIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IUserService userService)
    {
        _next = next;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) // called twice
    {
        int? userId = await _userService.GetUserIdByUid(decodedToken.Uid);
        await _next(context);
    }
}

app.UseMiddleware<UserIdMiddleware>();
```

It was probably my mistake, I forgot that I may have other threads on the client when debugging it, so I thought it would be one request. But The problem is with the wrong DI in middleware.

Why does it work this way? How to avoid it?

Comment: Unable to repro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try as below follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-7.0#per-request-middleware-dependencies):

```
public UserIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next )
    {
        _next = next;
        
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context,IUserService userService) 
    {
        int? userId = await userService.GetUserIdByUid(decodedToken.Uid);
        await _next(context);
    }
```

when it comes to why you get into InvokeAsync method twice,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-webapplication-1)

Comment: Yes, middleware is created once but Invoke is called multiple times which leads to errors. So the right way is to inject via parameters but not via a constructor.